# set function output type based on whether optional keyword argument present

Tags: julia

I need to make a histogram, and my data points each carry a statistical weight.  The standard `hist` function isn't equipped to handle this.  I *could* of course import the [numpy.histogram function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), which handles weighted data just fine, but I thought it would be a good exercise in learning julia to try and augment the `hist()` function to accept weights as an optional (named) argument.

I started by looking at the julia source for [hist()](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/3574b5c4e001a63c75364c9a6c2da54f1b9616c2/base/statistics.jl##L581-598), and was able to modify it slightly (if amateurishly -- suggestions for improvements welcome), to get it sort of working:

```
function sturges(n)  # Sturges' formula
    n==0 && return one(n)
    iceil(log2(n))+1
end

function weightedhist!{HT}(h::AbstractArray{HT}, v::AbstractVector, edg::AbstractVector; init::Bool=true, weights::AbstractVector = ones(HT,length(v)))
    n = length(edg) - 1
    length(weights) == length(v) || error("length(weights) must equal length(v)")
    length(h) == n || error("length(h) must equal length(edg) - 1.")
    if init
        fill!(h, zero(HT))
    end
    for j=1:length(v)
        i = searchsortedfirst(edg, v[j])-1
        if 1 <= i <= n
            h[i] += weights[j]
        end
    end
    edg, h
end

weightedhist(v::AbstractVector, edg::AbstractVector; weights::AbstractVector = ones(Int,length(v))) = weightedhist!(Array(Float64, length(edg)-1), v, edg; weights=weights)
weightedhist(v::AbstractVector, n::Integer; weights::AbstractVector = ones(Int,length(v))) = weightedhist(v, histrange(v,n); weights=weights)
weightedhist(v::AbstractVector; weights::AbstractVector = ones(Int,length(v))) = weightedhist(v, sturges(length(v)); weights=weights)
```

If I generate some random data with

```
v = randn(10^5);
w = rand(length(v));
edges = floor(minimum(v)):0.1:ceil(maximum(v));
```

then `weightedhist(v, edges; weights=w)` agrees with `numpy.histogram(v, edges, weights=w)`. If I leave out the optional keyword argument for weights, then `weightedhist(v, edges)` agrees with the built in `hist(v, edges)`, and `weightedhist(v)` agrees with the built in `hist(v)`, **except** for the fact that my function outputs floats rather than ints when no weights are provided.

I don't understand why this is the case (is h getting created as a float array?  promoted?), and I'd like for the my function to fall back on the behavior of the built in one as closely as possible when no weights are provided.

Can anyone suggest why my function is outputting floats, and how I might change that behavior to output ints when no weights are provided?  I'd like to do this without first creating the h array and then converting it from one type to another, since I'd like the code to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you call

```
weightedhist(v, edges)
```

you are using the first of your three "extra" definitions at the bottom.

This calls

```
weightedhist!(Array(Float64, length(edg)-1), v, edg; weights=weights)
```

so in your "main" `weightedhist!` the `HT` parameterization will be `Float64`, so `h` will be `fill`ed with `HT` == `Float64`, hence the `Float64` output. So changing it to `Array(eltype(weights), length(edg)-1)` would be sufficient, I believe.

Comment: I tried that initially, but while it outputs ints when there's no weights, it gives me an `InexactError()` pointing to the line `h[i] += weights[j]` when the optional weights argument is given.

Comment: Oh I see, that'd make sense (its trying to stuff Floats in an Int array, which it can't do safely, hence the inexact).

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `eltype`, which should handle it.

Comment: `eltype` was exactly what i needed!  worked perfectly.  thanks!